# How to create empty folder in UNC path in .net?

Tags: .net

I want to create an empty folder in UNC path and copy all the files from local disk to that particular empty folder. I tried `WDEngine.UploadFile` but it seems that it only works on local disks. `File.copy` works fine at copying all the files but the only problem lies at how to create an empty folder in UNC path in order to paste in all the files copied from local disk.

Appreciate your response, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `Directory.CreateDirectory` method.

Comment: @OOoi Eu Jeen
I think you got correct Solution.This Approach is correct to create Directory in the Given Path.